# Failed to install npm dev / npm watch for Laravel 5.6

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, laravel-5.6

I'm working on a project in Laravel 5.6, I've installed npm successfully, but when I run `npm run dev` or `npm run watch`, I get this error:

```
$ npm run dev

> @ dev C:\wamp64\www\QuAn
> npm run development


> @ development C:\wamp64\www\QuAn
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

11% building 9/14 modules 5 active ...elector.js?type=template&index=0!C:\wamp64\www\QuAn\resources\assets\js\components\ExampleComponent.vue{ parser: "babylon" } is deprecated; we now treat it as { parser: "babel" }.
78% module and chunk tree optimization unnamed compat pluginC:\wamp64\www\QuAn\node_modules\webpack\lib\Chunk.js:861
                throw new Error(
                ^

Error: Chunk.entrypoints: Use Chunks.groupsIterable and filter by instanceof Entrypoint instead
    at Chunk.get (C:\wamp64\www\QuAn\node_modules\←[4mwebpack←[24m\lib\Chunk.js:861:9)
    at C:\wamp64\www\QuAn\node_modules\←[4mextract-text-webpack-plugin←[24m\dist\index.js:176:48
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\wamp64\www\QuAn\node_modules\←[4mextract-text-webpack-plugin←[24m\dist\index.js:171:18
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\wamp64\www\QuAn\node_modules\←[4mwebpack←[24m\node_modules\←[4mtapable←[24m\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:12:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\wamp64\www\QuAn\node_modules\←[4mwebpack←[24m\node_modules\←[4mtapable←[24m\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.seal (C:\wamp64\www\QuAn\node_modules\←[4mwebpack←[24m\lib\Compilation.js:1342:27)
    at C:\wamp64\www\QuAn\node_modules\←[4mwebpack←[24m\lib\Compiler.js:675:18
    at C:\wamp64\www\QuAn\node_modules\←[4mwebpack←[24m\lib\Compilation.js:1261:4
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\wamp64\www\QuAn\node_modules\←[4mwebpack←[24m\node_modules\←[4mtapable←[24m\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:31:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\wamp64\www\QuAn\node_modules\←[4mwebpack←[24m\node_modules\←[4mtapable←[24m\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.finish (C:\wamp64\www\QuAn\node_modules\←[4mwebpack←[24m\lib\Compilation.js:1253:28)
    at C:\wamp64\www\QuAn\node_modules\←[4mwebpack←[24m\lib\Compiler.js:672:17
    at eval (eval at create (C:\wamp64\www\QuAn\node_modules\←[4mwebpack←[24m\node_modules\←[4mtapable←[24m\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:11:1)
    at C:\wamp64\www\QuAn\node_modules\←[4mwebpack←[24m\lib\Compilation.js:1185:12
    at C:\wamp64\www\QuAn\node_modules\←[4mwebpack←[24m\lib\Compilation.js:1097:9
←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)←[39m
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\INFO\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-20T21_53_25_570Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\INFO\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-20T21_53_25_604Z-debug.log
```

I've tried to clean the cache, delete node_modules, files and reinstall npm but nothing seems to resolve the problem.

Versions : `Laravel 5.6` , `Node 12.10` , `npm 6.11.3`

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution will help you [github](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1072#issuecomment-319401164) Read JeffreyWay comment

Try doing a full reset:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

Comment: I've tried this solution but i keep getting this error :

rm: cannot remove 'package-lock.json': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'yarn.lock': No such file or directory